# Content overlaps with navbar - need to scroll 'beneath nav'

Tags: html, css

I'm baffled. I've tried adding padding-top to my content, changing my nav from fixed to sticky, tried to hide with z-index etc...
My content doesn't scroll beneath the nav. they overlap.
[image]

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.nav-center {
    width: 90vw;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 1000;
}
.nav-center h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}



.articles {
    padding: 2rem 0;
    width: 90vw;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* padding-top: 128px; */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Add "background-color: white" to nav

Comment: @MannyAlvarado solved my issue.

Comment: Good to know. Please click on the up arrow next to my comment whenever you can :)